# Javascript Match and Find from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, reactjs

I have a JSON array more than 2k

```
const Keyword = [
 {
        "key": "hello",
        "word": "hi. how may i help you?"
 },
{
        "key": "how are you?",
        "word": "I'm good, what about you? "
 }
]
```

My word

```
hello , are you available right now?
```

now I need to match and find with JSON key hello with my word if match then return result true  or false,

I tried with this code below

```
const text = "hello , are you available right now?"
if (
      Keyword.find((arr) => arr.key.toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase()) ===
      undefined
    ) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
```

now the problem is its find the exact word but I need a solution to find with match

Thanks

Comment: You mean, like, `includes()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes. Also, are you sure you want `find` (returns first match) vs. `filter` (returns the whole set of matches)?

Comment: yah includes(), and find and filter doesn't matter I need a solution ..

Comment: Change: `Keyword.find((arr) => arr.key.toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase())` to `Keyword.find((arr) =>text.toLowerCase.inculdes(arr.key.toLowerCase()))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method on the string to check if it contains a substring

```js
const Keyword = [
 {
        "key": "hello",
        "word": "hi. how may i help you?"
 },
{
        "key": "how are you?",
        "word": "I'm good, what about you? "
 }
]

const text = "hello , are you available right now?"

const found = Keyword.find(item => text.toLowerCase().includes(item.key.toLowerCase()))
console.log(found)
```

Comment: I'm out of votes for today but this is how I do it.

Comment: And `const found = !!Keyword.find(item => text.toLowerCase().includes(item.key.toLowerCase()))` - for boolean result

Answer (score 0):

A simple function to find your Keyword using RegExp:

```js
const Keyword = [{
    "key": "hello",
    "word": "hi. how may i help you?"
}, {
    "key": "how are you?",
    "word": "I'm good, what about you? "
}]

const findKeyword = (text) => 
  Keyword.find(r => new RegExp(r.key, 'i').test(text))

console.log(
  findKeyword("Hello, are you available right now?")
)
```